# make child ul slide-down on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is like this

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li class="has-sub open ">
        <a href="/rigging.aspx " >  rig </a>
        <ul>
            <li class="has-sub ">
                <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">  rigging  </a>                   
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub ">
                <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">rig-3 </a>
            </li>                
        </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

on page load if any `<li>` has class `open` I want its child `<ul>` element to be slide down. I have written something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#cssmenu li').hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown();        
    }
}
```

But its not working (slide down not happens) can any one point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selects all `ul` children of li which have the class `.open` and applies slideDown.

```
$('#cssmenu li.open > ul').slideDown();
```

```js
$('li.has-sub > ul').slideDown();
```

```css
.has-sub > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-sub open ">
    <a href="/rigging.aspx ">  rig </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">  rigging  </a> 
      </li>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">rig-3 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub open ">
    <a href="/rigging.aspx ">  rig </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">  rigging  </a> 
      </li>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">rig-3 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="/rigging.aspx ">  rig </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">  rigging  </a> 
      </li>
      <li class="has-sub ">
        <a href="/rigging/rigging.aspx">rig-3 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```